# How to replace Linux Mint with Ubuntu without losing any internal data?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

In my Pc i am having Dual OS Linux Mint and Windows. I am facing lots of issues because of Linux Mint. I want to replace it with Ubuntu but at the same time i dont want to lose my internal data's like i have development setup's in it. there are lots of databases packages where installed.

if I changed it means will let me in lots of time loss. is there any way to replace it?

Comment: Mint is almost completely Ubuntu - basically there are some customized versions of the MATE desktop and a few other tools, everything else is Ubuntu.  So what exactly issues are you having that Ubuntu will fix that Mint cant'?

Comment: I its customized on top of ubuntu but still they have lots of bug. I got weird error. my system getting turned off, once i tried to upload file, print, save ( all happened during while popup occurs - save popup) also my mouse pad stop working once i logoff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a list of the installed pagkages with `dpkg --get-selections` and restore with `dpkg --set-selections`. You might also want to look into saving and restoring your package configuration database from Debconf (`debconf-[gs]et-selections`, from [`debconf-utils`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/debconf-utils)), and probably backup and restore all of `/etc` as well as `/home`.

As `root` on the source system,

```
dpkg --get-selections >packages
debconf-get-selections | grep -Ev '^[[:space:]]*(#|$)' >debconf_settings
tar jcf etc+home.tar.bz2 /etc /home
```

Save these files to a USB stick or something, set up the new system, then again as `root`, on the target system

```
dpkg --set-selections <packages
debconf-set-selections <debconf_settings
tar -C / -j -x -f etc+home.tar.bz2
```

I don't think this can be expected to work smoothly or flawlessly, but having a fair amount of shared packaging infrastructure means at least the trivial parts should not require a lot of manual work.

If you have the time and patience, maybe try this in a virtual host before entirely zapping your Mint install. Setting up Ubuntu in Virtualbox should be well worth your time for other reasons as well.

Comment: Commands adapted from https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2009/03/msg02350.html but notice it's from 2009.

Comment: Docker is much more lightweight than Virtualbox but it won't (easily) let you run a GUI.

Comment: The installer will of course ask you things which later will be overridden by the zapping of the Debconf database and the files in `/etc`.  Ideally, you would set up the installer to take its parameters from the saved Debconf database but I don't have the time to look into that.  Preseeding requires a slightly different format for the input file IIRC.  Moreover, you probably want to exclude some stuff from `/etc` (and probably `/home` too, like your browser's cache), in particular anything which is specific to Mint (`/etc/lsb-release` comes immediately to mind; probably `/etc/issue` etc too).

Comment: On an Ubuntu system, `fgrep -sil ubuntu /etc/*` produces the list `/etc/issue /etc/issue.net /etc/legal /etc/lsb-release /etc/os-release`